# what does f(A,i,mid) do?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, pseudocode

```
f(A, i, j) {
    print("f", i, j);
    n: = j - i + 1;
    mid: = floor((i + j) / 2);
    if (n > 1) {
        f(A, i, mid);
        f(A, mid + 1, j);
        g(A, i, j);
    }
}
g(A, i, j) {
    print("g", i, j);
    n: = j - i + 1;
    if (n == 2) {
        if (A[i] > A[j]) swap A[i] and A[j];
    } else {
        for (k: = 0 to n / 4 - 1) swap A[i + n / 4 + k] with A[i + n / 2 + k];
        // swap 2nd and 3rd quarters
        g(A, i, i + n / 2 - 1); // recurse on 1st and 2nd quarters
        g(A, i + n / 2, j); // recurse on 3rd and 4th quarters
        g(A, i + n / 4, i + 3n / 4 - 1); // recurse on 2nd and 3rd quarters
    }
```

So i assumed that f(A,0,3) and A= [ 4,2,3,1]
after going through the code i can see that mid is = 1 and that n=4 which means n >1 so this is where I get confused what exactly does f(A,i,mid) do? and what is f and g?

Comment: It would be easier to read (and therefore understand) what the code does if it was consistently indented.

Comment: Why not simply run it on a computer?

Comment: its psuedocode I thought we couldnt?

Comment: Please don't remove code relevant to understanding the question and answers. I have reverted your last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `f` and `g` are simple recursive functions, f(A,i,mid) is just a call to the original function f(A, i, j). Take some values like f(A,0,3) and A= [ 4,2,3,1] and carefully go through the code.

I just convert it into java, I found the following output:

Input:

```
int[] A = { 4, 2, 3, 1 };
f(A, 0, 3);
```

Output:

```
f: 0, 3
f: 0, 1
f: 0, 0
f: 1, 1
g: 0, 1
f: 2, 3
f: 2, 2
f: 3, 3
g: 2, 3
g: 0, 3
g: 0, 1
g: 2, 3
g: 1, 2
```

If you need the full code, here it is, you can play with whatever input you like,

```
public class SomeRecursion
{
   static void f(int[] A, int i, int j)
   {
      System.out.println("f: " + i + ", " + j);
      int n = j - i + 1;
      int mid = (i + j) / 2;
      if (n > 1)
      {
         f(A, i, mid);
         f(A, mid + 1, j);
         g(A, i, j);
      }
   }

   static void g(int[] A, int i, int j)
   {
      System.out.println("g: " + i + ", " + j);
      int n = j - i + 1;
      if (n == 2)
      {
         if (A[i] > A[j])
         {
            // swap A[i] and A[j];
            int t = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = t;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         for (int k = 0; k < n / 4; k++)
         { // swap 2nd and 3rd quarters
           // swap A[i + n / 4 + k] with A[i + n / 2 + k];
            int t = A[i + n / 4 + k];
            A[i + n / 4 + k] = A[i + n / 2 + k];
            A[i + n / 2 + k] = t;

         }
         g(A, i, i + n / 2 - 1); // recurse on 1st and 2nd quarters
         g(A, i + n / 2, j); // recurse on 3rd and 4th quarters
         g(A, i + n / 4, i + 3 * n / 4 - 1); // recurse on 2nd and 3rd quarters
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] A = { 4, 2, 3, 1 };

      f(A, 0, 3);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main function is `f(A, i, j) { ... }`.

Inside that function, the statement **`f(A, i, mid)`** is a **[recursive call](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion)** to that same function, with parameters `A`, `i` and `mid`.

To see what happens in more detail, you can simply insert more `print` statements.

Here is a translation of the `f()` function into Javascript, with more printing, `g()` removed, and added depth tracing and text indentation:

```js
function f(A, i, j, depth) {
  const indent = "   ".repeat(depth);
  console.log(indent + "f called with A=[" + A.toString() + "], i=" + i + ", j=" + j + ", depth=" + depth + ".");
  let n = j - i + 1;
  let mid = Math.floor((i + j) / 2);
  console.log(indent + "n=" + n + ", mid=" + mid + ".");
  if (n > 1) {
    console.log(indent + "We found n is > 1 --> Enter recursion");
    console.log(indent + "Start 1st recursive call:");
    f(A, i, mid, depth + 1);
    console.log(indent + "After 1st recursive call.");
    console.log(indent + "Start 2nd recursive call:");
    f(A, mid + 1, j, depth + 1);
    console.log(indent + "After 2nd recursive call.");
  }
}

const A = [4, 2, 3, 1];
f(A, 0, 3, 0); // Added a 0 parameter for initial recursion depth value
```

Comment: so i = 0 and mid =1. so f(A,i,mid) what does it do exactly. im abit confused. what would the code print if f(A,0,3)